# Is there any difference between a static time series regression model and a model of a cross section?

Tags: regression, model

Is there any difference between a static time series regression model and a model of a cross section? In an econometrics class I am taking, I was told that the definition of a static time series model is one where "the current value of one variable is modeled as the result of the current values of explanatory variables."

Answer (score 1):

The main difference would be in the assumptions about the error term.

In a time series model, even a "static" one, one would have to consider autocorrelation in the error term.

In a cross-sectional model, we usually consider the case of heteroskedasticity in the error term.

So for example, if in both cases we assume white-noise errors, the two models are essentially identical as regards their mechanics.

Comment: I suppose heteroskedasticity could arise in time series models as well, so we are talking about an added feature (autocorrelation) rather than an alternative feature (to heteroskedasticity).

Comment: @RichardHardy Autocorrelation could also arise in cross-sectional models, when _spatial_ order matters. My answer http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/112964/28746 has a real-world example on the matter.